# Does facebook use comet or long polling for getting new stream and messages?

Tags: comet, long-polling, reverse-ajax

I would like to know if there are any code references that I can follow to write a very simple example. Many posts or websites just talk about the technology.

Comment: No idea about Facebook, but I was able to find quite a few comet examples by simply doing a google search for "comet tutorials", including this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824604/online-tutorials-for-implementing-comets-server-push) on SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes "it's a variation of **Comet**, specifically **XHR long polling**, and/or **BOSH**."

reference site:

> https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919